# Jssor Slider - combined two sliders not nested - second one not responsive

Tags: jssor

I have combined two (did not nest them but bottom one is a nested slider) Jssor sliders and top slider is responsive but not bottom one. I changed variables to unique names in responsive coding for second but still no responsivity only on second slider. Hints?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is to scale slider while window resize.

```
        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodyWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 980));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        ScaleSlider();

        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            $(window).bind('resize', ScaleSlider);
        }


        //if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/)) {
        //    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //}
        //responsive code end
```

Please make a bit change to resize both sliders at the same time.

```
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodyWidth) {
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 980));
                jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 980));
            }
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
```